# Как сделать кнопку с дополнительным контентом?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать кнопку, в которой будет разделительная черта и картинка?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой вариант - в `button` добавить отдельно текст и иконку, к иконке добавить `border-left`

```css
@import url('//fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons+Outlined');

.btn {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #2ac880;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn span:nth-child(1) {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.btn span:nth-child(2) {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,.35);
  padding: 10px 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">
  <span>1%/$1</span>
  <span class="material-icons-outlined">add</span>
</button>
```